# How to add a userCustomAction at SiteCollection level in SharePoint Online using Console application?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I'm injecting CSS & JS files using a `UserCustomAction` through a console application. I am using the below code to create a new `userCustomAction`:

```
UserCustomAction cssAction = web.UserCustomActions.Add();

cssAction.Location = "ScriptLink";
cssAction.Description = actionName;
cssAction.Sequence = 0;
cssAction.ScriptBlock = @"document.write('<link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""" + fileurl + @""" />');";
cssAction.Name = actionName;
cssAction.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This code is working fine but injecting files at web level only. I need to inject them on the whole site collection so that sub sites can also have the same kind of branding. Can anyone help me out how can I apply them at Site Collection level or how can I use Scope in this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is how you are creating the UserCustomAction.

You have `UserCustomAction cssAction = web.UserCustomActions.Add();` where `web` is likely a SPWeb object.

When you should do `UserCustomAction cssAction = site.UserCustomActions.Add();` where `site` is  the SPSite object.

Without modifying much code here, you could just do `UserCustomAction cssAction = web.Site.UserCustomActions.Add();`

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. Its working fine for me.. thanks once again!